# Microprofile Config injection is null during custom OASFilter processing and microprofile-config.propetries is not considered as config source

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, openapi, microprofile

I'm in the process of preparing a custom OpenAPI generator, to make the generated docs generic. The problem that I've encountered is some strange behavior when trying to inject the *org.eclipse.microprofile.config.Config* into class which extends *org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.OASFilter*. The Config object cannot be resolved by the Wildfly CI/CD container, even though resolving it through the factory method succeeds in doing so.
[image]

Resolving the Config reference still, however, is not solving my problem of being able to read the content of META-INF/microprofile-config.properties at this point, even though later on, during execution of @Startup bean, it gets resolved correctly. Any reason as of why, the behavior of injecting is different? I'm using an official Wildfly 19 image.

EDIT: The main problem is that the content of microprofile-config.properties is ignored when looking up for the properties

Comment: What do you get when you print out all the sources? config.getConfigSources().forEach(System.out::println);

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the microprofile specification about processing annotations inside filter.

But approach with `ConfigProvider`, as you found out, works fine.

I suggest that you obtain config right before you need it ie:

```
Config config = ConfigProvider.getConfig();
String keycloakUrl = config.getValue("OAUTH_URL", String.class);
```

[Microprofile OpenAPI specification][1]
https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-open-api-1.1/microprofile-openapi-spec.html#_oasfilter

Comment: I've probably phrased my problem in a bit wacky way. The main problem is that the META-INF/microprofile-config.properties is not considered as a config parameters source, even though the file is ready by the Microprofile OpenAPI itself, because even in the referenced documentation there is a mention of setting up the config in the aforementioned file.